# How will a NPK 15-0-15 fertilizer affect this soil?

Tags: environmental-chemistry

If the soil we have has pH 7,2 and we want to add this fertilizer which has 15-0-15 (NPK). What should the fertilizer contain in order for the pH to get reduced?

I believe that $\ce{K+}$ ions should derive from $\ce{KCl}$ because it won't affect the pH.If it comes from $\ce{K2SO4}$, the soil will be more alkaline.
I'm confused about the nitrogen. Should it come from urea or NH4NO3? I believe that if the ions come from urea it will be more alkaline. Or should it come from $\ce{(NH4)2SO4}$?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labeling_of_fertilizer) Wikipedia article has tables of different fertilizers and their composition with respect to their NPK content. For example, the fertilizer _sylvite_ is a naturally occurring mineral of KCl that is 0-0-63. Most of the fertilizers are of course synthetic mixtures. Also note that the value for P is reported as $\ce{P2O5}$ and K as $\ce{K2O}$. K and P are not actually present as these species, this is just a convention for reporting their values. This doesn't answer your pH question directly, but I'd still check out the above link.

Comment: @airhuff Thank you! My question is on a theoritical level. I just ran into this question and I was curious and confused. The only reason  I mentioned those compounds was because they were as choices.

Comment: OK, I didn't quite get the context ;) What you've said about K and urea is correct, and the chemistry for the ammonium compounds is a bit more complex. However, if you read the Wikipedia pages for the ammonium compounds, I think it will be clear which one will be likely to acidify the soil.